# Open chrome profil with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm trying to open a browser with my default chrome profil. I need to do so because I have an extension with preloaded features on my chrome profil that I want to use through puppeteer.

This is what I did :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function startBrowser(){
    let browser;
    const proxy = 'http://my.proxy.com:3001';
    try {
        console.log("Opening the browser......");
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath: "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
            userDataDir: "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data",
            headless: false,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Could not create a browser instance => : ", err);
    }
    return browser;
}
```

A window does open in my current browser but this is what I got:
[blank page][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGEWQ.png
and I got this error message: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
But the code is working when I'm not trying to execute it with my own profil.

What else can I do to open a browser with my profil in puppeeter ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to execute it with your profile? This looks like an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I want to execute it with my profil because I use an extension with it with preloaded configurations on it that I need to access. It would be too complicated for me to reopen the extension through a new chrome profil and reload all the features.

Comment: niceman an idea then ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.